# Tabbing out of the "to:" field in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

I noticed recently that I can't seem to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move on to the `Subject` field in Gmail. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> simply inserts a tab, which is rather useless in the `To` field.

Is that new or have I just not noticed it up until now? Is there a way to fix that?

It's possible that this is affected by a lab setting, but I don't think I have any related labs enabled. Still, just in case labs are relevant, here's the list of the ones I have enabled:

- Mark as Read Button
- Quote Selected Text
- Send & Archive
- Sender Time Zone
- Title Tweaks
- Undo Send
- Unread Message Icon

If all else fails, is there a shortcut to focus on the `Subject` field?

Comment: Works for me with my GMail account and Chromium 13.0.782.215. (Thanks for the list of labs, by the way. I think I'll keep them all enabled.) What version of Chrome are you running and have you tried using Chrome's (little-known) profiles feature to test in a fresh browser profile?

Comment: @ssokolow I'm running the same version. Tell me more about this fresh profile feature? Thanks!

Comment: In your case, the simplest way to test would be as described [here](https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059) but, if you want to flip between multiple profiles without renaming or run multiple instances of Chrome at once, the closest built-in equivalent to Firefox's `-profilemanager` switch is [here](http://www.chromeplugins.org/tips-tricks/how-to-create-profiles-in-google-chrome/). (Though it's more a replacement for Firefox's `-P` than `-profilemanager`)

Comment: @ssokolow I tried it with an incognito window and the tabbing works as expected. Weird. I guess doing a profile reset would be an option, but that's unfortunate. Thanks for your help. :) If you post your debugging tips as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it works for me with the same list of labs and Chromium 13.0.782.215 and you said you're using the same version, I suspect it'd either be something else in your GMail settings (which you ruled out when the Incognito Window didn't exhibit the problem) or something in your Chrome profile.

I can see three potential sources for the problem on the client side:

1. Flawed extension. (Fixed by a new profile. Fixed by an Incognito Window unless you've chosen to allow the broken extension in Incognito.)
2. Corrupted profile. (Fixed by a new profile. Anybody's guess whether a given instance of corruption will be fixed by Incognito Window.)
3. Strange config tweak in your Chrome. (Fixed by a new profile. Not fixed by Incognito Window.)

Chrome has primitive support for running with multiple profiles which you can use for testing. There's a [quick-and-dirty approach](https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059) and a [cleaner approach](http://www.chromeplugins.org/tips-tricks/how-to-create-profiles-in-google-chrome/) for long-term use.

Since you said the Incognito Window fixed it and you didn't mention any other problems in your Chrome, my guess is that it's probably a bug in one of your extensions that's causing the extension to grab the Tab keypress but then make the flawed assumption that injecting a tab character is the way to say "on second thought, use the browser's native handler after all".

Comment: [Textarea code formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgkbnngeehclnibbdblaimapibmmcdal) turned out to be the culprit. Thanks again for your help!